# (Swift) How to access assign something to a navigationItem of a ViewController from another view controller?

Tags: swift

ViewController A:

self.navigationItem.titleView = ActivityIndicator.showActivityIndicator("Updating location...")

... after some time the self.navigationItem.titleView should be set to nil from another view controller:

ViewController B:
ViewControllerA.navigationItem.titleView = nil

but that doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide the perfect formatting and share the source code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try belong this code.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

I think it's helpful.